# How to show mysql data in html input box using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I am creating a simple order taking page. What I want is when I will start typing on the select customer input box , filtered based on my key stroke result will be shown below the input box.

As I am new in this field your advise / suggestion will be highly appreciated.

here is my javascript code :

```
function showCustomer(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","searchcustomer.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

## Here is my searchcustomr PHP code

```
 $q=$_GET["q"];

 define('HOSTNAME', 'localhost'); 
 define('USERNAME', 'root'); 
 define('PASSWORD', ''); 
 define('DBNAME', 'order'); 



    $conn = new mysqli(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME);
    $sql = "SELECT cusname, cusarea, cusadd1,cusadd2,cusadd3,cuscity,cuspin,cusoldbal FROM tbl_customer where cusname like '%".$q."%'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data = $row['cusname'];

    }
        echo $data;
                                }
    else
    {
        echo 'No Mach Found...';
    }


    $conn->close();
```

## here is my HTML input file:

```
<h4>Order To</h4>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control autocomplete_com" data-type="clientCompanyName" name="clientCompanyName" id="clientCompanyName" placeholder="Select Company"  onkeyup="showCustomer(this.value)">
</div>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

This div txtHint just not working, I just want the result below my input box and able to select too.....What will  be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: What is the current result? What debugging have you done? Have you checked the request and response in your browser's developer tools? One obvious issue is that you are overwriting `$data` each time through your `while` loop. You also say "and able to select too", but there is no indication here of how you would be "select"ing anything.

Comment: Put an else block and print response inside onreadystatechange in js block. Try calling "searchcustomer.php?q=aba" in browser URL bar directly. Given that it is a get call, it will show something; at least an error. 

BTW, document.getElementById("txtHint") is used inside showCustomer which is called onKeyup. Better to move that out in a variable for performance reasons.